# Difficulty with fitting Gaussians in 3D with Numpy arrays using conjugate gradient method

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, gaussian, gradient-descent

Essentially, I will have some 3d intensity distribution, where in a simplified version of my problem I will have some Gaussian centered at a point in 3D space, represented by a 3D numpy array, defined as:

```
I = np.zeros((ny, nx, nz))
tolerance = 1e-4 # minimum value of Gaussian for compact representation
sigma = x[1]-x[0] # Gaussian width
max_dist = sigma*(-2*np.log(tolerance))
di = np.ceil(max_dist/dx) # maximum distance in compact representation, in index format

# Create intensity field/true Gaussian
# this exists separately as its own function synth_I() where [0] is instead for each particle [i]
ix = round((xp[0] - x[0]) / dx) # index of particle center
iy = round((yp[0] - y[0]) / dy)
iz = round((yp[0] - y[0]) / dz)
iix = np.arange(max(0, ix - di), min(nx, ix + di), 1, dtype=int) # grid points with nonzero intensity values
iiy = np.arange(max(0, iy - di), min(ny, iy + di), 1, dtype=int)
iiz = np.arange(max(0, iz - di), min(nz, iz + di), 1, dtype=int)
ddx = dx * iix - xp[0] # distance between particle center and grid point
ddy = dy * iiy - yp[0]
ddz = dz * iiz - zp[0]
gx = np.exp(-1 / (2 * sigma ** 2) * ddx ** 2) # 1D Gaussian
gy = np.exp(-1 / (2 * sigma ** 2) * ddy ** 2)
gz = np.exp(-1 / (2 * sigma ** 2) * ddz ** 2)
gx = gx[np.newaxis,:, np.newaxis]
gy = gy[:,np.newaxis, np.newaxis]
gz = gz[np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :]
I[np.ix_(iiy, iix, iiz)] = I[np.ix_(iiy, iix, iiz)] + gy*gx*gz
```

The idea is to fit some a series of Gaussians, varying their amplitudes, centered at a finite number of grid points (chosen as those with an intensity above a minimum threshold, 0.5 in this case) to some unknown intensity distribution, using a gradient descent algorithm due to the convexity of the problem but also due to scaling concerns.

We want to minimize [image: \frac{1}{2}\sum_{x_v}\left [ I(x_v)-\sum_{i=1}^{N}s_iG(x_v;x_i,\sigma)) \right ]^2] where x_v represents all the grid points, while G represents the value of a Gaussian centered at grid point x_i at a given grid point x_v with amplitude s_i. This has the following gradient:

[image: df/ds_j = \sum_{voxels} 2(I(x_v) - \sum_{i=1}^N s_i G(x_v; x_i,\sigma)) G(x_v; x_j, \sigma)]

And this gradient is implemented with the following code:

```
def diff_and_grad(s):  # ping test this:
    part_params = np.concatenate((xpart, ypart, zpart, s)) # for own code
    # create an intensity field as a combination of Gaussians as above
    synthI = synth_I_field_compact(part_params, nd, sigma, x, y, z)
    Idiff = I - synthI # difference in measurements
    f = 0.5 * np.sum(np.power(Idiff, 2)) # objective function
    g = np.zeros(Np) # gradient
    for i in range(0, Np):
        ix = round((xpart[i] - x[0]) / dx)
        iy = round((ypart[i] - y[0]) / dy)
        iz = round((zpart[i] - z[0]) / dz)
        iix = np.arange(max(0, ix - di), min(nx, ix + di), 1, dtype=int)
        iiy = np.arange(max(0, iy - di), min(ny, iy + di), 1, dtype=int)
        iiz = np.arange(max(0, iz - di), min(nz, iz + di), 1, dtype=int)
        ddx = dx * iix - xpart[i]
        ddy = dy * iiy - ypart[i]
        ddz = dz * iiz - zpart[i]
        gx = np.exp(-1 / (2 * sigma ** 2) * ddx ** 2)
        gy = np.exp(-1 / (2 * sigma ** 2) * ddy ** 2)
        gz = np.exp(-1 / (2 * sigma ** 2) * ddz ** 2)
        Id = Idiff[np.ix_(iiy, iix, iiz)]
        g[i] = -Id.dot(gz).dot(gx).dot(gy) # gradient is -product of local intensity difference with gaussian centered at grid point
    return f, g
```

However, for an initial estimate of amplitude taken as the value of the intensity measurements at the corresponding grid points, this analytical gradient differs from one found with a finite difference scheme, and thus the cg algorithm does not work:

[image: gradient difference]

However, after a couple days of debugging, I have been unable to find the source of the problem. A similar method of calculating the gradients for a different problem is used with much of the same code, and as well this implementation works in 2D without the z axis contributions as well. There must be something fundamental I am missing, but I am not sure what.

I have a copy of the full test code at https://pastebin.com/rhs4tasZ for any additional information needed, or for anyone who wants to run this code themselves

Comment: Did you check your gradient function e.g. against np.gradient or numdifftools, maybe as a start, on slices through the origin in every plane? Did you check the same slices against each other using your function. Should be the same for all, right? If it is not, the error is in the other part of the code.

Comment: Next thing: use Mayavi to plot your distribution and the gradient in 3d. That way you can easily see, if there are some issues and where they are.

Comment: I used a pingtest in the pastebin code and the cost function gradients differ. However, the strange thing is that when all z axis stuff in the code is removed (i.e. reducing the problem to 2D), the cost function analytical and finite difference gradients match to machine precision.

Comment: Maybe you should remove all the copy paste typos :) Pastebin Line 22, Line 65 That could fix the `z` deviation.

Comment: Why is the gradient image so coarse and not around 30 data points like the gradient function? Is this cropped?

Comment: Oh wow I did not notice that, thanks. Though unfortunately it wasn't the source of the issue.

Comment: Regarding the coarseness: essentially the idea is that a Gaussian decays quite quickly, and thus only affects a finite region around it. Therefore, when calculating the cost function gradient, the difference between the intensity and Gaussian sum is only evaluated by summing the product of the difference and the ith Gaussian in a finite region around the ith Gaussian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem, I'll close this question now. I extracted the wrong parameters for z in synth_image